# Zend View - Automatically escape assigned variables

Tags: zend-framework, xss, zend-view

The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.scripts.html) for `Zend_View` shows an `escape($var)` method. It also suggests that it should be manually invoked for each variable we want to display: `$this->escape($this->var);`

Is there a way to extend `Zend_View` to automatically escape?

Comment: https://github.com/jensklose/ZendX_View_Autoescaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a risky thing to consider for two reasons.

Firstly, the type of escaping required depends on the context in which the variable is output. E.g. outputting a string in the middle of some HTML requires different characters to be escaped than outputting it within some `<script>` tags, or as the value of a HTML attribute.

Secondly, what would you do about objects? Consider `echo $this->name` vs. `echo $this->user->name` (where `$this->user` is a instance of a class). In the latter example `->name` could even be a dynamically generated string that is the result of a `__get()` call. There's no way for this to be auto-escaped, so you end up in a situation where some of your data is auto-escaped and some hasn't. Arguably this is less secure than the out-of-the-box-escape-it-yourself approach, as it provides a false sense of security.

Comment: I don't get the problem. 

Let's assume one is only interested in HTML escaping. Having `$this->escapeHtml` calls all through your views seems a little verbose/repetitive/ugly. So why not escape by default?

That's how you can do it in Smarty:

$smarty->escape_html = true; / escaped: {$variable} / not escaped: {$variable nofilter}.

I don't see why an auto escape function wouldn't be able to handle the example you give. It simply gets the return value from the call and then HTML escapes it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is implementable by using a custom View class that employs a custom stream handler.

Details of such an implementation are provided by Rob Allen at http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/a-view-stream-with-zend_view/.